# how to write a Precompiled query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can somebody help to write a pre-compiled query for the following code?

```
Modal.StaffNo def = Staff.StaffNo.Where(a =>
 a.Number1 == number1 && a.Number2 == number2
 ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Show you effort first. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you asking for a pre compiled query using CompiledQuery class (LINQ to Entities) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the query for above linq something like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM StaffNo Where number1=@number1 and number2=@number2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope I can help you:

```
Modal.StaffNo def = (from o in Staff.StaffNo where o.Number1 == number1 && o.Number2 == number2 select o).FirstOrDefault();
```